# MS Access select between two dates?

Tags: date, ms-access, between

I have searched, but all results didn't help me to understand.

I need to select names of people who are 18-23 years old.
So my try was:

```
WHERE ((People.Birth) Between (Now()-Year(18)) And (Now()-Year(23)))
```

What I'm doing wrong? Solution as #some_date# is a bad idea!

Comment: Have you investigated what `Year(18)` actually returns?

Comment: See [datediff](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f).

Comment: f*ck, so much times understood, that all probles need to solve after sleeping, not after 25 hours day. Year(18) returns 1900...                     
2 user2864740 - I've seen it, but it doesn't helped me(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a true solution, you need to use *DateAdd* and a function like this:

```
Public Function AgeSimple( _
  ByVal datDateOfBirth As Date) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full years from datDateOfBirth to current date.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'
' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
' After an idea of Markus G. Fischer.
'
' 2007-06-26. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim datToday  As Date
  Dim intAge    As Integer
  Dim intYears  As Integer

  datToday = Date
  ' Find difference in calendar years.
  intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", datDateOfBirth, datToday)
  If intYears > 0 Then
    ' Decrease by 1 if current date is earlier than birthday of current year
    ' using DateDiff to ignore a time portion of datDateOfBirth.
    intAge = intYears - Abs(DateDiff("d", datToday, DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDateOfBirth)) > 0)
  End If

  AgeSimple = intAge

End Function
```

Then your query will have this *where* clause:

```
WHERE AgeSimple(People.Birth) Between 18 And 23
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it by simple

```
WHERE ((People.Birth) Between (Now()- 365*18) And (Now()-365*23))
```

If you have better solution- welcome