SQL Issue: calculated query column won't recognize day interval in DateDiff?
For some reason I can't get my calculated query column to recognize a day interval. Every time I test run the form that displays the query results, a parameter pop-up asks me to enter the value of d.
This is my SQL column formula:
ExceedsTime: (IIf(IsNull([CloseOutDate]) And (DateDiff(["d"],[SurveyDate],Now())>45),1,0))

Basically I need to count any results where the Survey has not been completed within the 45-day deadline.
If we're running past the deadline, return a 1 value toward the total count.  If we're still within the 45-day window, return a 0 value.
SurveyDate = Day the survey was conducted
CloseOutDate = Day the survey is completed.

I've tried it anyway my peanut brain can reword it.
Is there any way I can make it recognize day as any interval and not a parameter value?

Try to remove square brackets ["d"] -> "d"

Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61107475/2144390

@Gord Thompson: A text box expression was the first thing I tried before trying SQL.  Am I just asking the query field too much?  I'm not sure how to build this calculation in vba; that's why I hoping to accomplish this with a calculated query field.

I am unclear on where this calculated field is being created. A calculated field in the table itself? A calculated field in a View (Select Query)? A calculated control on a Form (or Report)?

I'm working in the design and SQL view of a query right now.

This is odd. DateDiff should work in query. However, Day is default unit for date arithmetic. Why use Now() instead of Date()? What happens with: AND Date()-[SurveyDate]>45?

I'm not entirely sure why the SQL insists on putting the d interval in brackets, so I've just decided to split the expression.
For the calculated query field, I've shortened it to only give me count totals:
ActiveDays: (Abs(IIf(IsNull([CloseOutDate]), ([SurveyDate]-Date()))))

Then I had to calculate the average of those totals on the form:
=Avg([ActiveDays])


DateDiff defined as
DateDiff(interval, date1, date2[, firstdayofweek[, firstweekofyear]])

where interval is string.



Part
Description




interval
Required. String expression that is the interval of time you use to calculate the difference between date1 and date2.



In your case interval="d"
(DateDiff("d",[SurveyDate],Now())

If you write ["d"], this interpreted by Access as variable or column name "d".

Interesting: your syntax rule implies that firstweekofyear can't be specified without specifying firstdayofweek also. Microsoft site shows: DateDiff ( interval, date1, date2 [, firstdayofweek] [, firstweekofyear] ), i.e. you can skip firstdayofweek and just specify firstweekofyear but how would it know what you intended (that seems wrong, too). Maybe brackets around firstdayofweek, as well?

In help file is exact [, firstdayofweek[, firstweekofyear]] - so, can not skip firstweekofyear before firstweekofyear

In Microsoft site this syntax quite differences for language setting:). Your example for en-us. Also, firstadayofweek acceptable for intervals "w" and "ww".

@tinazmu, thank you for a curious detail.

I have tried removing the brackets several times, but the calculated field automatically wraps "d" in brackets ever time I tab or enter out of the field.

If you use Query constructor, try remove brackets in SQL mode.

@ValNik, Tried it.  As soon as I save the changes and test run the query, the parameter still appears for "d" or "dd."  :-/

Probably should have included that detail in your question. As is, it was not clear you had attempted expression without those brackets and that Access was adding them.
