# How to calculate Employee Service in MS Access and save in Table Fields. (not via query)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am facing regarding the `EmployeeServiceWithUs` (Field in table, datatype is Number) in "years".

In `TxtServiceWithUs` I use the following and Result is OK:

```
Control Source=DateDiff("yyyy",[DateOfJoing],Date())
```

But in following:

```
Private Sub EmployeeServiceWithUs_LostFocus()

[EmployeeServiceWithUs] = [DateOfJoing] & (DateDiff("yyyy", [DateOfJoing], Date))

End Sub
```

I get:

> error "2113 The value you enter is not valid for this field.

Is the able syntax is wrong?

Comment: Remove `[DateOfJoing] &` and just save difference in years.

Answer (score 0):

DateDiff calculates the difference in calendar years, not _years of service, or *age* or similar. You will need a custom function like *AgeSimple* found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331016/ms-access-select-between-two-dates/35332808#35332808).

Then your *ControlSource* becomes:

```
=AgeSimple([DateOfJoing])
```

To update a (temporary) table:

```sql
Update
    YourTable
Set
    [EmployeeServiceWithUs] = AgeSimple([DateOfJoing])
```

Comment: Its working Perfect on Control Source. Requirement of my project to Save values (years) at Table Level in the Field Name [EmployeeServiceWithUs]. Although it is not recommended to save in Table Field. But due to the requirement, i want to save in field. Kindly guide.

Comment: That would be a simple update query. See extended answer, please.